# ng build spills a lot of errors... can't launch my app

Tags: angular, angular-cli

I don't know what happened. I was coding... then everything just broke.

When I run `ng build` or `ng serve`, I now get the following error messages:

> ERROR in ./node_modules/saucelabs/index.js Module not found: Error:
>   Can't resolve './lib-cov/SauceLabs' in
>   '/Users/mlgyshan/Documents/GitHub/Nutanix2/FlexMachineLearning/FlexMachineLearning/static/node_modules/saucelabs'
>   ERROR in ./node_modules/protractor/built/runner.js ...

---

I ran `npm i` and it gave the following output:

> npm WARN codelyzer@3.2.2 requires a peer of @angular/compiler@^2.3.1
>   || >=4.0.0-beta <5.0.0 but none is installed. You must install peer
>   dependencies yourself. npm WARN codelyzer@3.2.2 requires a peer of
>   @angular/core@^2.3.1 || >=4.0.0-beta <5.0.0 but none is installed. You
>   must install peer dependencies yourself. npm WARN tsickle@0.30.0
>   requires a peer of typescript@>=2.4.2 <2.9 but none is installed. You
>   must install peer dependencies yourself.
>
> audited 29419 packages in 9.015s found 58 vulnerabilities (19 low, 28
>   moderate, 11 high)   run `npm audit fix` to fix them, or `npm audit`
>   for details

Comment: did you `npm i` before trying `ng serve`? Because the errors seens like you are missing a lot of dependencies.

Comment: Yes. I added the output to my question above.

Comment: How about deleting `node_modules` and running `npm i` again?

Comment: @askYous if removing/installing node_modules you might be in dependency hell, where you conflicting library versions in your package.json

Comment: I received the same error when removing `node_modules` and running `npm i`. I found out that when I undo my changes (on git), the error disappears. I'll check that out.

Comment: So it's probably is what @rhavelka is talking about. Maybe you added some dependency that isn't compatible with the rest of your project.

Comment: Yes... I referenced the wrong dependency. I found out the [problem](https://stackoverflow.com/a/52544231/1404347).

Answer (score 25):

I found out what happened. I had this line:

```
import { EventEmitter } from "protractor";
```

But I had to change it to this:

```
import { EventEmitter } from "@angular/core";
```

Comment: I removed import { Key } from 'protractor' and it fixed

Comment: Thank you! I lost some hours searching this problem.